# Saber en que ruta se instalo una aplicacion comando Linux

Tags: linux, debian

Quiero saber la ruta donde se instalo un programa, ahoralo busco con el comando `dpkg -l | grep repo` y obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ese resultado ejecuto los comandos `whereis jaspersoftstudio` y `find -executable -iname "jaspersoftstudio"` ,lo mismo con `which -a jaspersoftstudio` pero no estoy obteniendo nada,

¿Como podría encontrar la ruta en donde esta el ejecutable de la aplicación?

Comment: que distribucion de Linux esta utilizando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Linux mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el programa que buscas es para entorno gráfico, lo mas normal es que tenga un [archivo `.desktop`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) con cierta información para que los entornos gráficos lo muestren en su menú.

Estos archivos `.desktop` están en `/usr/share/applications`.

También puedes buscarlo dentro del archivo de información del paquete. En distribuciones basadas en Debian, la base de datos de los archivos instalados se encuentra en `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. Consta de varios archivos, de entre los cuales, los que nos interesan son los terminados en `.list`.

Un archivo `.list` no es mas que una una lista de archivos (1 por línea), incluyendo la ruta completa.

Así que podríamos hacer

```
fgrep .desktop /var/lib/dpkg/info/jaspersoftstudio.list
```

Una vez localizado el archivo `.desktop`, no tenemos mas que mirar en su interior buscando la *clave* `Exec=`:

```
fgrep Exec= `fgrep .desktop /var/lib/dpkg/info/jaspersoftstudio.list`
```